# Logical Address Space is Larger than Physical and Backing store combined

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, mmu

When a virtual address space is larger than the physical memory, OS can use swapping to evict page frames (e.g. LRU eviction). CPU generates Page Fault where then page that is in disk is swapped into the main memory. What happens when the virtual address is large enough that neither primary memory or disk have enough storage to hold it? What happens when a page frame is not in the disk either? Is another page fault called?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when the virtual address is large enough that neither primary memory or disk have enough storage to hold it?

A virtual memory system maintains an image of the logical address space in secondary storage. A well-designed operating system is not going to allow a process to map a logical address that does not have a backing already in secondary storage. When your application calls a system service to map pages to the logical address space, the call will fail if there is no secondary storage available for the pages.

> What happens when a page frame is not in the disk either?

There are some poorly designed operating systems that will map pages without having secondary storage behind them. You call the system service to map pages, it succeeds even if the pages could not be backed in secondary storage. 
In that case, you get a memory exception upon access (and get no hint in your application that the real problem as a memory allocation failure).

> Is another page fault called?

No.

In a logical memory system (as supported by most processors) a page has two states:

```
1. Mapped
2. Unmapped
```

In a virtual memory system, there are three states:

```
1. Mapped
2. Unmapped and valid
3. Unmapped and invalid
```

When a page fault occurs, the processor just knows the page is not mapped to memory. The operating system then has to figure out if the page is in secondary storage somewhere. If it is not, the operating causes the process to see an exception. If it is, the operating system loads and maps the page, the lets the process continue on its merry way.

Answer (score 0):

> When a virtual address space is larger than the physical memory, OS can use swapping to evict page frames (e.g. LRU eviction)

Lets assume that a virtual address is 48-bit (so the size of one virtual address space is 256 TiB), and you're running 123 processes where each one has its own virtual address space. This adds up to a total of 31488 TiB of virtual address space. *Note: This is "very normal" for a modern 80x86 PC running a modern OS (Windows, Linux, ...).*

Out of this 31488 TiB:

- almost all of it will be unused and marked as "not present". If software tries to access it you get a page fault, the page fault handler realizes it's a bug, and you probably end up with a `SIGSEGV` (or "blue screen of death" or ...). Because it isn't being used the OS doesn't need any RAM or any disk space for it.
- some of it will be the same things loaded into RAM once and then mapped into many virtual address spaces. This is extremely common for the kernel itself and for shared libraries/DLLs. It also includes cases where the same RAM is used for the virtual file system cache and for memory mapped files, or the same RAM is mapped into 2 or more processes as "shared memory", or when the same RAM is mapped into 2 or more virtual address spaces as "copy on write" (e.g. in the aftermath of `fork()`).
- some will be "allocate on write" - literally the same page full of zeros mapped at many virtual addresses in many virtual address spaces, where if you write to it you get a page fault and the page fault handler allocates a new page of RAM for the page you tried to write to. This allows the OS to pretend that a huge amount of virtual space is allocated and filled with zeros without using any RAM or any disk space (until it actually is modified).
- some will be (modified) data that is unique to a specific process.

The end result is that the 31488 TiB of total virtual space might only need a few GiB of RAM (and probably won't use swap space at all).

**Over-commit**

The OS does a pile of tricks to pretend memory was allocated when it actually wasn't. This creates the potential for a worst case where all the memory the OS pretends is allocated actually does need to be allocated. There are 2 ways to deal with this:

a) Refuse to let processes allocate more if you can't cover the worst case (e.g. return a "not enough memory" error when a process tries to allocate more than the OS can supply). This is bad because the worst case is extremely unlikely and you end up with software failing for no reason ("not enough memory" when there's actually plenty of memory to cover current requirements).

b) Allow processes allocate more (within reason), even if you can't cover the worst case. This works fine most of the time, but if the worst case actually happens something has to break (e.g. the OS terminates a process to free up some RAM).

The best option (in my opinion) is the first option (don't allow over-commit), but to have a large amount of swap space. Essentially; this is like "allow over-commit of RAM, but don't allow over-commit of swap space + RAM"; where the OS will probably be running slowly (due to excessive swap space use) before it has to start telling processes "no more memory"; and where most of the time everything will be in RAM (and ideally swap space is only used to cover the unlikely worst case).